# SQL Server Trigger After Update

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

i made an stored proc

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[MakeOrder]
@barcode varchar(50),
@packs int ,
@units int,
@Eid int 
as
begin

insert into Orders (Barcode,Price,PacksQty,UnitQty)
values        (@barcode,dbo.GetOrderPackPrice(@packs,@barcode)+dbo.GetOrderUniPrice(@units,@barcode),@packs,@units)

insert into OrderDetails(Eid,Date)
values (@Eid,GETDATE())

update Product
set Stock = Stock-@packs , UnitsStock = UnitsStock-@units where BarCode=@barcode

end
```

and i want to make after update trigger on product table to check the value of UnitsStock Column After Update If it 0 do something else do another thing

Comment: You shouldn't open *duplicate* questions - if you've got improvements to make, you should *edit* your existing question rather than posting a new one. That being said, you've put more effort into this one so I voted to close the [older one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426629/after-update-trigger-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: okai thank you and sorry for that mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a trigger to do this necessarily. You can simply select the value of this column out again:

```
DECLARE @currentUnits int
SELECT  @currentUnits = UnitsStock FROM Product WHERE BarCode = @barcode
```

and then build in some conditional logic:

```
IF @currentUnits <= 0
BEGIN
    -- Do something
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Do something else
END
```

Since you're not checking whether the number of units being ordered is less than the current UnitsStock, you're better off with a check for `<= 0`, or maybe even a separate check for `< 0` to handle this differently still.

This code should go in your stored procedure, after the `UPDATE` statement.